# How to use a connection string to connect to an odbc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odbc, connection-string, informix

Simply put I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UCCXConnection" connectionString="DSN=UCCXWALLBOARD;Uid=uccxwallboard;Pwd=whatever;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've copied a normal SqlClient connection string and altered it to the DSN keyword for use with an odbc. Of course this won't work as the DSN keyword is invalid for this kind of connection strings.

What other changes or frameworks are needed to be able to use a connection string to connect to an odbc?

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="ODBCDataConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=ODBCServer;"
      providerName="System.Data.Odbc"
    />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35c54x95(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That got me to the error "No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.Odbc'". Which got me to the answer to add the entityFramework tag to my Web.config file. Which again got me to the error that the providers/provider tag inside entityFramework is not supported. Which makes me think something is wrong and that I need another way of making "System.Data.Odbc" work.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ConnStr[256] = 
"DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};SERVER=my_ids_server_name;
DATABASE=my_ids_databasename;HOST=my_host.my_domain.com;
PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;SERVICE=5550;UID=my_username;PWD=my_pwd;";

SQLDriverConnect( hdbc, NULL, ConnStr, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT );
```

FYI:
If 64bit driver then

```
DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)}
```

If you are using DSN then

```
char ConnStr[256] = "DSN=my_dsn_name"
```